# What does the -x operator mean in Perl?

Tags: perl

I saw something like:

```
if (-x $program) {
   system("$program");
   if ($?) {
      // do something
   }
}
```

What does the -x and $? mean here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`-x`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) is an operator documented in [perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html) under the heading of `-X`. You can use `perldoc -f -x`.

[`$?`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$?) is variable set by some operators. It is documented along the other special variables in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), and in the [operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) that set it. You can use `perldoc -v '$?'`.

Answer (score 1):

From [`perldoc -f -X`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)

> -x  File is executable by effective uid/gid.